# Java looping through list problem

Tags: java

```
    if (sList.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tList.size(); i++) {
            String a = sList.get(i).getString();
            String b = tList.get(i).getString();
            if (a.equals(b)) {
                tList.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

sList.Size is 1, tList.size is 100.

However, I keep getting this error:
    Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

I don't understand why this is, I have also tried iterators, same problem.

Comment: when you remove an item from the list, the list's size changes!.. But "i" increases so eventually you will end up with an invalid/out-of-bound value ...

Answer (score 1):

that's because you're looping through slist in your loop which only has 1 element in it. When i > 0 that exception will occur, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

you are iterating over `tList` which you said has size 100, but `sList` only have size 1.  So as soon as you get to the second item of `tList` you have already exceeded the size of `sList`.

Note that you can use `removeAll` to remove everything in `sList` from `tList`.  Just make sure your `equals` and `hashCode` methods are correct.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if sList contains fewer items than tList. You need a separate loop counter for iterating through the elements of sList, rather than trying to use a single counter for both.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating for 0 to 100 (the size of `tList`).  You say that the size of `sList` is 1, but you are trying to access `sList[i]`.  So you are reading out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually iterating through `sList`, you're only going through `tList` (line 2) and assuming `sList` has the same number of elements (line 3) which it doesn't... as soon as you're done the first element (0) which is in both it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Java lists are indexed (like all other collections) are indexed from 0. A list of length 1 has only a member at position 0.

If you try to access a member that doesn't exist (which you are doing here) then you will get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

If `sList.size()` is `1` then you can only get item at index `0` and not `1`, hence why you're getting

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

So, when `i == 1`, you're already reading going out of bound (remember, java counts from `0` and not `1`).